# What is an adequate Ubuntu/Xubuntu version for a MacBook late 2007 (4GB RAM)?

Tags: xubuntu, macbook

I have a working Xubuntu release 14.04 on my MacBook late 2007. The system suggests upgrading to release 16.04 LTS, but upgrading seems to not be working. My Mac has 4GB of RAM. Should I upgrade and how?

Comment: You will want to post more details as to why the upgrade is not working. What is the error you are receiving, etc.?

Comment: 14.04 is still supported for quite a while. However, Xfce 4.12 in 16.04 has some nice new features. 16.04 should work fine on your machine. MacOS and Windows tend to get more bloated with each release, but Linux distros (particularly with Xfce) are not this way.

Comment: Finally and without known motive, the upgrade to 16.04 worked. Maybe my source was not available yesterday.